# Can't get deviceToken from appDelegate in right moment

Tags: iphone, ipad, appdelegate

I have an initial view controller in storyboard, called `LoadAppViewController`. In this view controller in method viewDidAppear I send a request for server to update data on my phone.

Now the thing is - in this request I send a device token for push notifications. But, as I noticed, it sends Null instead the device token. As I understood the problem is the AppDelegate class is called after method viewDidAppear is performed.

My question is - how can I solve this issue?
By the way - this problem appears only when I run app on iPad, on iPhone in method viewDidAppear class AppDelegate is already called and everything is fine.

Comment: Are you saying `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of AppDelegate is called only after `viewWillAppear` of your First view controller? Can you double check?

Comment: are you tested in Device... >

Comment: Questions says, he used iphone and ipad, so it seems he **did** test on device

Comment: Just tested in iPad. Result - awakefromNib - viewDidLoad-ViewWillAppear-then applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions-viewDidAppear. and after viewDidAppear I can use deviceToken. Sorry, looks like the title of this quesiton is wrong, but problem is the same - i cant get the device token in viewDidAppear

Comment: any ideas what can be wrong in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

device token is not dependent on any of your view controller's loading time or on-screen appearing time.

from applicationDidFinishedLaunching, you should trigger request for getting device token from apple. then you need to wait till you get response (either - failed/success)
When your delegate is called successfully with:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

then proceed with your further process where you are sending device token to server.

Comment: its up to you. you can either not load it or you can move your code out from viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear and make it a method. you can call it once u get a confirmation that you have received devicetoken

Comment: The problem is     
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken calling after viewDidAppear.

Comment: Or tell your LoadAppViewController when you get the token with a "deviceToken" property or method.

Comment: but still - why on iPhone it works fine but on iPad it doesnt?

Comment: its just a matter of luck that on iphone you are getting devicetoken quicker than ipad the but there will be cases where iphone as well will fail. but in either of the case you should fix your implementation.

Comment: but how can I tell my loadAppViewController to load after I called successfully didRegisterForRemoteNotification?

Comment: you can make a protocol and implement in your receiver controller or you can use NSNotificaitonCenter postNotificaiton etc... that you have to think of..which is more suitable for you. I have made you aware of the problem..

Comment: I'm just a beginner in Objective-C=) but thank you very much for help